# JQ subtracts 13 from my integer when it adds it to a second location, but not the first

Tags: json, bash, precision, jq

I have a script that uses Docker env vars to configure a json file on start. The function uses the same ENV var twice in the same JQ command, and in the first location the integer remains as set, and in the second line JQ subtracts 13 (WTF?) from the number. Can anyone explain this? And more importantly how do I prevent this from happening.

*Note:* In order for the config to be valid, the second instance must be an unquoted integer. Testing shows that quoting the integer results in the expected output, but invalid config.

Env Var

```
DISCORD_CHANNEL=448887356515418113
```

Bash Function:

```
function updateDiscordConfig {
  echo "Setting Discord configuration..."
  jq ".discord |= . + {\"token\":\"${DISCORD_TOKEN}\"} | .discord.channels.channels |= . + {\"${DISCORD_CHANNEL}\": {}} | .minecraft.dimensions.generic |= . + {\"discordChannel\": [${DISCORD_CHANNEL}]}" ${DISCORD_SRCCONFIG} | sponge ${DISCORD_DESTCONFIG}
}
```

Output:

```
// First output
"channels": {
  "448887356515418113": {}
}

// Second output
"discordChannel": [
    448887356515418100
],
```

*Update*: I've replaced the second instance update with a line using sed:

```
function updateDiscordConfig {
  echo "Setting Discord configuration..."
  jq ".discord |= . + {\"token\":\"${DISCORD_TOKEN}\"} | .discord.channels.channels |= . + {\"${DISCORD_CHANNEL}\": {}}" ${DISCORD_SRCCONFIG} | sponge ${DISCORD_DESTCONFIG}
  sed -i "/discordChannel/c\   \"discordChannel\" : [${DISCORD_CHANNEL}]," ${DISCORD_DESTCONFIG}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @chepner - I guess they deprecated the triple tick notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you've run into one of the major limitations of the C-based implementation of jq - numerical precision.  This implementation maps JSON numbers to IEEE 754 64-bit numbers. This is discussed in the [jq FAQ](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ) under "Caveats".

### Workarounds

(1) Use gojq, the Go implementation of jq.

(2) If you don't want to work with the C implementation of jq,
you could use the "BigInt" module for jq - https://gist.github.com/pkoppstein/d06a123f30c033195841

However, this works with string representations, so it may be more trouble than its worth for your use case.

If you just need addition, you could use this jq def:

```
# The args should be strings representing non-negative integers
# without a leading "+":
def add(num1;num2):
  if (num1|length) < (num2|length) then add(num2;num1)
  else  (num1 | explode | map(.-48) | reverse) as $a1
      | (num2 | explode | map(.-48) | reverse) as $a2
      | reduce range(0; num1|length) as $ix
          ($a2;  # result
           ( $a1[$ix] + .[$ix] ) as $r
           | if $r > 9 # carrying
             then
               .[$ix + 1] = ($r / 10 | floor) + 
                            (if $ix + 1 >= length then 0 else .[$ix + 1] end )
               | .[$ix] = $r - ( $r / 10 | floor ) * 10
             else
               .[$ix] = $r
             end )
      | reverse | map(.+48) | implode
  end ;
```

#### Usage

One way to use this would be to copy it to a file (say add.jq) in your jq library (e.g. ~/.jq/)
and use `include` to include it, e.g. as illustrated by the following:

```
jq -n  'include "add"; 
        add("448887356515418113";"448887356515418113")'
"897774713030836226"
```

Comment: Any recommendations for a work around? I was originally thinking `sed` but it seemed a nasty solution for json.

Comment: Thank you for the added options.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you should not use the numeric type for large numeric strings in JSON for exactly this reason. But if Discord requires an integer - and if it's able to get the correct unrounded value out of the config with whatever *it's* using to parse it - then you need another approach. Perhaps Python?

```
function updateDiscordConfig {
  echo "Setting Discord configuration..."
  python -c "import json, sys; conf = json.load(sys.stdin); conf['discord']['token']='$DISCORD_TOKEN'; conf['discord']['channels']['channels']='$DISCORD_CHANNEL';conf['minecraft']['dimensions']['generic']['discordChannel']=[$DISCORD_CHANNEL];print(json.dumps(conf));" ${DISCORD_SRCCONFIG} | sponge ${DISCORD_DESTCONFIG}
}
```

Comment: Please read the note that specifies that the config requires an integer in order to be valid.

Comment: I like this solution. Cleaner than using jq and sed together. I should just rewrite the whole start script into python, it's getting more complicated than I originally envisioned.